How can I create four columns for an entry in the CurVe class for CVs?
So I'm using LianTze Lim's A Customised CurVe CV to create my CV. Instead of 3 columns for an entry (key, prefix, text) I would like to have 4 (key, prefix, text, anotherkey). The aim is to make this "anotherkey" right-aligned. It should also only take up as much space as needed. In the end I want to create something like (unfortunately I don't know how to set column width in MarkDown, but the key, prefix and anotherkey columns should have a width that's equal to its largest entry):



key
prefix
text
anotherkey




2023-2024
*
First entry
$ 5.000


2023
*
Second entry
$ 10.000


2022-2023
*
Third entry
$ 600



Here is how an entry is defined in the documentation
\def\@maybekey#1{%
  \def\@newkey{#1}%
  \ifx\@previouskey\@newkey\else%
  #1\gdef\@previouskey{#1}%
  \fi}

\def\@key#1{#1}
\DeclareOption{skipsamekey}{\let\@key\@maybekey}

\newcommand\@entry[2][]{%
  \gdef\@nextentry{}\egroup% end of \noalign opened in \entry.
  \@key{#1}&\@prefix&#2\\}   

\newcommand\@sentry[1][]{%
  \gdef\@nextentry{\\}\egroup% end of \noalign opened in \entry.
  \@key{#1}&\@prefix&}

\newcommand\entry{%
  \@nextentry
  \noalign\bgroup\gdef\@beforespace{-\subrubricbeforespace}%
  \@ifstar{\@sentry}{\@entry}}

I don't know how to alter this function or overwrite it (like what was done in this post for the prefix argument). So, how do I add a 4th argument to a \entry* command for the LaTeX CurVe class?

Welcome. // Luckily for this CV-template there is a manual at ctan: https://ctan.org/pkg/curve . I suggest to study that one first. // In general you could replace \newcommand by \renewcommand and modify there, i.e. put that one intor your preamble after using the CV-package. // You may also click on the tag and have a look at similar or related problems and solutions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curve-class

Hi there! This manual is not unfamiliar to me. I studied it already and it gave me great insight into some of the functions. I also already checked out all the other posts in the curve-class tag before posting. I didn't see a similar question where I could deduce what I should do (I figured I should do something with \makeatletter). Therefore, could you give me a head start by writing such a \renewcommand?

https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Commands#Overwriting_existing_commands
